# Decode FOUR_BITS of a byte in a byte array (in C)

Tags: c

I am writing a code to decode the byte array based on user input (EIGHT_BITS at a time or FOUR_BITS at a time). I've actually managed to decode the byte array based on EIGHT_BITS. Now I want to decode them in terms of FOUR_BITS.

```
INT DecodeElem(UINT8 *decodeBuf, UINT8 elemlen, UINT8 *tempBuf, UINT8 elemlength){

  if (elemlength== EIGHT_BITS){
    *tempBuf = getByte(decodeBuf + decodeByteCount);
     decodeOffset = 0;
     decodeByteCount++;
  }
}
```

ie, if the elemlength= FOUR_BITS, I need to decode the first four bits of a particular byte in the byte array. Could someone let me know how do I do the same without modifying the case for the EIGHT_BITS which I have written above?

What I basically need is another if statement with if (elemlength == FOUR_BITS)

Note: tempBuf is CHAR * type and I can't change the type.
decodeByteCount and decodeOffset are global variables; *decodeBuf is the already encoded byte array which needs to be decoded. elemlen is for future use and I will take care of it.

**This is my getByte function:**

```
UINT8 getByte(UINT8 *byteBuf)
{
  return ((UINT8)*byteBuf);
}
```

Comment: You need to mask off the upper 4 bits and then the lower 4 bits of each input byte and do some bit shifting...

Comment: Could you please give me a pseudo code for the same? I am confused how to do bit shift and masking on *tempBuf. I know how to mask and shift, but not sure how to do it here on *tempBuf.

Comment: Does each input byte contain only one output byte? I.e. are the remaining 4 bytes not used? Or is the data packed?

Comment: I have all the 8 bits filled in all the bytes. Once if I know how to deal with the first 4 bits, I can take care of the remaining 4 bits... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what decodeOffset and decodeByteCount does....
It should be something like that (assuming each byte has 2 4 bit values. If the assumption is wrong remove "/2" from the code):

```
if (elemlength== FOUR_BITS){  
    *tempBuf = getByte(decodeBuf + decodeByteCount / 2);
    if(decodeByteCount % 2)
        *tempBuff = (*tempBuff & 0xF0) >> 4;
    else
        *tempBuff = (*tempBuff & 0Xf);
    // ???decodeOffset = 0;
    // ???decodeByteCount++;
}
```

Comment: "%" (modulo) remainder of division of one number by another.             x % 2 = 0 if x is even. x % 2 = 1 if x is odd number.

Comment: But hey, when I do the >> operation on *tempBuf, it gives me an error: '>>' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned char *'. Any workaround?