# Bit operations on CHAR * in C

Tags: c

With reference to this thread: [Decode FOUR_BITS of a byte in a byte array (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359060/decode-four-bits-of-a-byte-in-a-byte-array-in-c/15359290?noredirect=1#comment21700340_15359290)

The member idooo has given me a solution which can be seen there which involved a bit operation on a CHAR *. When I tried to compile, it gave me the error: **'>>' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned char *'**

I am looking for a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

PS: I can't change te data types. And the code snippet is given in that thread where I am doing the operations. Variables and their scopes are also explained there.

Comment: If you check closer, you will see that the answer is using the _dereferencing operator_ to convert the `char *` to a `char`.

Comment: Take-home message: you should copy and paste code, not re-type it, otherwise you are likely to introduce errors.

Comment: The compiler gave an error saying that the left operand has type unsigned char*. Then the cause of the error was found: the left operand had type unsigned char*. Didn't see that one coming!

Answer (score 2):

The bit operations are on the *dereferenced* pointer, the type of which is `char`, not `char *`.  So, if you have a `char *ptr`, your shift expression should be `*prt >> 4`, not `ptr >> 4`.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob... How do I modify the (*tempBuff & 0Xf) statement in the other thread then? I am passing the base address of tempBuff to the DecodeElem function and receiving it as *tempBuff, and then trying to do the operation (*tempBuff & 0Xf) after getting a byte on tempBuff...

Comment: @BryanAdams How is `tempBuff` declared? As for being a noob, that is easily fixable, just get a good book on C. I recommend "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, the inventors of the language.

Comment: Declaration of tempBuf: **CHAR *tempBuf = (CHAR *)ALLOC(sizeof(CHAR)*100);**

Thanks for the recommendation. I've also done a research and planning to get that book asap :)

Comment: @BryanAdams Sorry, I don't understand what exactly is the problem — if `tempBuf` is declared as `char *`, then `*tempBuf` should be a valid operand of the `<<` operator. Please edit your question to include a **compilable** code sample that demonstrates the error.